# How can I randomly assign powers to my heroes?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm creating a hero game. I've created a dictionary containing magic powers, my problem is how can I create a method that will randomly assign 12 magic powers to 4 of my heroes (each hero get's 3 powers) without one magic power being assigned multiple times?
Here's my code:

```
import random
class Heroes:
    def __init__(self,name,type,magic,health):
        self.name = name
        self.type = type
        self.magic = magic
        self.health = health

class Stats:
    def __init__(self,hero):
        self.hero = hero

    def magic(self):
        magic_powers = {1: {'Name': 'Apparition', 'Damage': 10},
                  2: {'Name': 'Astral Spirit', 'Damage': 15},
                  3: {'Name': 'Dawnbreaker', 'Damage': 20},
                  4: {'Name': 'Solar Guardian Land', 'Damage': 25},
                  5: {'Name': 'Pulse Nova', 'Damage': 30},
                  6: {'Name': 'Lifestealer', 'Damage': 35},
                  7: {'Name': 'Medusa', 'Damage': 40},
                  8: {'Name': 'Tree Dance', 'Damage': 45},
                  9: {'Name': 'Assassin', 'Damage': 50},
                  10: {'Name': 'Psionic', 'Damage': 55},
                  11: {'Name': 'Mine', 'Damage': 60},
                  12: {'Name': 'Templar', 'Damage': 65}}
        print(random.choice(magic_powers))

hero1=Heroes('Gandalf','Wizard', '?', 500)
hero2=Heroes('Gandalf','Wizard', '?', 500)
hero3=Heroes('Gandalf','Wizard', '?', 500)
hero4=Heroes('Gandalf','Wizard', '?', 500)
heroes=Heroes(hero1,hero2,hero3,hero4)
stats = Stats(heroes)
magic_powers=stats.magic()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This goes through the set of 12, and if you ask for more, it will reshuffle them again.

```
import random

class Heroes:
    def __init__(self,name,type,magic,health):
        self.name = name
        self.type = type
        self.magic = magic
        self.health = health

class Stats:
    magic_powers = {1: {'Name': 'Apparition', 'Damage': 10},
              2: {'Name': 'Astral Spirit', 'Damage': 15},
              3: {'Name': 'Dawnbreaker', 'Damage': 20},
              4: {'Name': 'Solar Guardian Land', 'Damage': 25},
              5: {'Name': 'Pulse Nova', 'Damage': 30},
              6: {'Name': 'Lifestealer', 'Damage': 35},
              7: {'Name': 'Medusa', 'Damage': 40},
              8: {'Name': 'Tree Dance', 'Damage': 45},
              9: {'Name': 'Assassin', 'Damage': 50},
              10: {'Name': 'Psionic', 'Damage': 55},
              11: {'Name': 'Mine', 'Damage': 60},
              12: {'Name': 'Templar', 'Damage': 65}}

    def __init__(self,hero):
        self.hero = hero
        self.powers = None

    def magic(self):
        if not self.powers:
            self.powers = list(range(1,13))
            random.shuffle(self.powers)
        return self.powers.pop(0)

hero1=Heroes('Gandalf','Wizard', '?', 500)
hero2=Heroes('Gandalf','Wizard', '?', 500)
hero3=Heroes('Gandalf','Wizard', '?', 500)
hero4=Heroes('Gandalf','Wizard', '?', 500)
heroes=Heroes(hero1,hero2,hero3,hero4)
stats = Stats(heroes)

print( stats.magic() )
print( stats.magic() )
print( stats.magic() )
```

Comment: I don't quite understand this since you are not shuffling my dictionary but numbers from the range of 1 to 12? I don't understand how would I go printing this, if print(stats.magic()) prints out number 7, how can I connect it to my dictionary and print out the values there?

Comment: You can't really shuffle a dictionary, but since the keys for your dictionary are integers, isn't it clear that if you get a 7 then you'd grab `Stats.magic_powers[7]`?

Comment: I can print it out if I say at the end of the line 'print(Stats.magic_powers[7])'. My trouble is making an if loop, so if  'stats.magic()' prints out 7, I want it to print out the index [7] of my dictionary and not the number itself. I'm currently having a problem with this, your method for getting a random number works great, now I only have a problem printing out the dictionary index instead of random number.

Comment: I just told you that.  `stats.magic()` delivers you a number.  That number can be an index into `Stats.magic_powers`.  If ALL you want to do is print them, `for i in range(12):` / `print(Stats.magic_powers[stats.magic()])`, but I assume you want to do more than just print them.

Comment: @TomRobers I think I have to redo the whole thing without the use of dictionary. Thanks for your help and yes I want to do more than just print out indexes.